# Turn CMake warning about unused options into fatal error

Tags: cmake

When a manually-specified CMake option is not used, CMake emits the following warning message:

```
CMake Warning:
   Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:
 
     MYVARIABLE
```

This is sometimes the sign that the name of the variable was misspelled.

Is there a way to turn this warning into a fatal error?

Comment: As far as I understand current CMake policy, it supports interpretation as errors only for those warnings, which are originated from the **project** itself (`CMakeLists.txt`). The warning "Manually-specified variables were not used by the project" is not from that class, so CMake doesn't support automatic transforming into the error.

Comment: what version of CMake are you using? see also https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-warn-unused-vars

Comment: @starball CMake 3.25.1.